# RFacebook Authentication Error

Tags: r, facebook, api, token

I got fb_OAuth to work. My browser says authentication successful and tells redirects me to R. However this is what appears:

```
Copy and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings:    http://localhost:1410 
When done, press any key to continue...
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
Error: Deprecated: supply token object to config directly"
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being discussed [here](https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook/issues/38).
Apparently, there is an issue with `httr`, on which `rfacebook`'s FB authentication function is based.

You can try the following:

**Install an older version of `httr`**

You can try downloading the tar.gz files from Cran's archive

```
#Credit to Thomas Leeper from whose answer the following was copied
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package
#for example of ggplot2
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot2/ggplot2_0.9.1.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

or you can try `install_version()` function from the `devtools` package

**Generate a temporay authentication**
by visiting this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
and then pasting the token you acquire into any functions of `rfacebook` that require an access token.

---

**Update**

As of August 6th, the package author has [sorted the problem out](https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook/issues/38#issuecomment-128504071) - it is now possible to complete the authentication process without ending up in an error.