# Install old version of DBI in R (2.5.0)

Tags: r, package, installation

How to install DBI with R (version 2.5(windows))? I am unable to install DBI (0.2)

I used:

> ```
> install.packages("DBI", repos="http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI/DBI_0.2-0.tar.gz")
> ```
>
> It gives error:
>
> Warning in install.packages("DBI", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI/DBI_0.2-0.tar.gz") :
>     argument 'lib' is missing: using 'C:\Users\USER\Documents/R/win-library/2.7'
>   Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI/DBI_0.2-0.tar.gz/bin/windows/contrib/2.7
>
> Warning message:
>   package ‘DBI’ is not available

If i used the process used in the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package)(suggest as a duplicate question).
I get this error:

> install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI/DBI_0.2-0.tar.gz",repos=NULL, type="source")
>
> Warning in install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI/DBI_0.2-0.tar.gz",  :
>     argument 'lib' is missing: using 'C:\Users\USER\Documents/R/win-library/2.7'
>
> Can't locate R/Dcf.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C \PROGRA~2\R\R-27~1.0\share\perl; /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at C:\PROGRA~2\R\R-27~1.0/bin/INSTALL line 23.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\PROGRA~2\R\R-27~1.0/bin/INSTALL line 23.
>
> Warning message:
>   In install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI/DBI_0.2-0.tar.gz",  :
>     installation of package 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI/DBI_0.2-0.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status

How to install old version of DBI in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing older version of R package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package)

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Comment: Do you have [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed?

Comment: yes, Rtools is already installed

Comment: Try looking at [this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/0415wnx9d0/r-build-r-package-on-winxp) and see if it helps.