# Errors Installing previous version of ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis, install.packages

Upon updating ggvis to 0.4.3, the shiny application I built was no longer working.  I am therefore trying to revert ggvis back to the previous version, however, when I run the following code:

```
foo <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggvis/ggvis_0.4.2.tar.gz"
install.packages(foo, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

based on this post: [Installing older version of R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package)

This is the result in the console.  I have replaced the name of the company and user in the directories with "company" and "user" respectively for discretion.

```
Installing package into ‘\\company/user/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggvis/ggvis_0.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 728345 bytes (711 KB)
downloaded 711 KB

'\\company\user'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'ggvis' ...
** package 'ggvis' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
Warning in file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file '\\company/user/R/win-library/3.3/ggvis/doc/index.html': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing vignettes failed
* removing '\\company/user/R/win-library/3.3/ggvis'
* restoring previous '\\company/user/R/win-library/3.3/ggvis'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "\\company\user\R\win-library\3.3" "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuOIfA9/downloaded_packages/ggvis_0.4.2.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuOIfA9/downloaded_packages/ggvis_0.4.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The result is either ggvis stays as version 0.4.3.

I tried the exact same code to revert back to 0.4.2 on another machine running the same version of RStudio (3.3.1) on a mac instead of my windows machine and it worked just fine.  I am at a loss as to why I am not able to reinstall 0.4.2 of ggvis on my machine.
Thanks

Comment: If you are planning to install from a local copy, then you should use your system facilities to download it first (and expand it). Then it has a chance of being where it is expected when repo="NULL".

Comment: @42- I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean.  I have downloaded the 0.4.2 file from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggvis/ on my windows machine and the .tar.gz file is currently in the downloads folder, but do not know what you mean by expand it or that it should be done from the system facilities.  I'm assuming when you say install from a local copy, you mean going to 

Tools >> Install packages >> Install from: (select drop down)

Package Archive File(.zip, .tar.gz).

Choose your newly-downloaded-package-zip-file and install the package

Comment: @42-
I tried what I put above both before and after extracting the files with 7zip, neither of which worked.  Is that what you were suggesting?