# RTextTools --> create_matrix function call throwing an error not found

Tags: r

```
install.packages('RTextTools')
library(RTextTools)

data("NYTimes", package='RTextTools')
head(NYTimes)

timesMat <- create_matrix(NYTimes$Title)
```

I can view the data "NYTimes" but call to create_matrix throws error that function not found.

while call to library I see the below error:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[i]]) :    there is no package called ‘slam’ Error: package or
>   namespace load failed for ‘RTextTools’

Please help...

Comment: In other Q&A with similar errors, a look at `.Rprofile` was helpful, esp. non-existing packages from former versions ...

Comment: What version of R and the package are you using (see the output from `sesssionInfo()`). Do you get any messages/warnings when you run `install.packages()`?

Comment: Using R 3.2.5..install.packages('RTextTools') gives the message "package ‘RTextTools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked" but
library(RTextTools) gives the above error:  When I try to install slam package, I get the error "Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘slam’ is not available (for R version 3.2.5)"

Comment: The current version of `slam` on CRAN requires `R (≥ 3.3.1)`. You can either upgrade R or [install an old version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package) of `slam`.

Comment: Thank you..upgraded R to the latest version and can install packages like RTextTools/tm.