# How do you read the helpfile/manual for an older version of a package function without installing the package?

Tags: r, dplyr

From [Installing older version of R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package), I am able to download the source for `dplyr` version `0.4.3`. I would like to see the helpfile for the function `collect` from this release, as I believe its behaviour has changed in `0.5`.

How do I see the old manual/help file without installing the old package?

Comment: You can go to the [archive page](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/) for the package, and download the package zip file for whichever version you wish. Then unzip the file and look in the `man` folder to find the help for each function.

Comment: Thanks, but this is unformatted roxygen code.

Comment: True. But you can open the file in an RStudio sesson and click "Preview" to see a formatted version in the Help window. There may be better/easier ways, but I was able to download the zip file and view a formatted help page within a couple of minutes.

Comment: FYI, for the `collect` help, look in the `compute.Rd` file, as `compute`, `collect`, and `collapse` have a single help page called `compute.Rd`.

Comment: thanks, it took a while to find that. Again it would be very good to be able to access an archived version of the manual.

Comment: For changes between versions, you can also check the [News page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/news.html) for the package.

Comment: Helpful as well, but this one was undocumented, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714170/how-do-i-see-the-help-for-this-method

Comment: If it's on GitHub, the most direct route would be to look at the history for the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that no one mentioned this:

[compute in dplyr 0.4.3](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.4.3/topics/compute)

[compute in dplyr 0.5.0](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/compute)

1. find package in [RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/)
2. select package and version
3. search function for documentation. Though `collect` is actually documented in `compute`. Maybe you would need a google search to find about this if you didn't know it beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Search https://www.rdocumentation.org/ for the package or search the function.

Hope it helps.