# How do I see the help for the `dplyr::collect` method?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find out what additional arguments can be passed to `dplyr::collect` in the ellipsis `...`. I want to do this because I believe that the behaviour of `collect` has changed between `dplyr` version `0.4.3` and `0.5`. It seems that in the new version `collect()` only downloads the first 100k rows, unless a new `n = Inf` argument is passed.

I have retrieved the methods associated with `collect` using:

```
> methods('collect')
[1] collect.data.frame* collect.tbl_sql*   
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

I have looked at the help file for S3 `methods` but cannot work out how to get help on `collect.tbl_sql`, as `?"dplyr::collect.tbl_sql"` does not work.

Comment: There is no help page for that method. Although you can always examine the code yourself. `getAnywhere(collect.tbl_sql)` or `dplyr:::collect.tbl_sql`

Comment: I think you are right!

Comment: Does the `*` mean not exported from the name space?

Comment: @Alex exactly. Which is why you can't call it directly when after `library(dplyr)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by [Chrisss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2860938/chrisss) and [Zheyuan Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891738/zheyuan-li):

1. The asterisk/star/* next to the method name after running `methods` indicates that each of these methods are not exported from the `dplyr` namespace.
2. To access the helpfile, one then needs to use three colons, i.e., `?dplyr:::collect.tbl_sql`
3. However, there is no helpfile for these methods, so we need to examine the source code to look at the behaviour of each of these functions in the respective versions.

In `0.4.3` by examining `tbl-sqr.r` file in the [source code](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.4.3.tar.gz):

```
collect.tbl_sql <- function(x, ...) {
  grouped_df(x$query$fetch(), groups(x))
}
```

and in `0.5`:

```
> dplyr:::collect.tbl_sql

function (x, ..., n = 1e+05, warn_incomplete = TRUE) 
{
    assert_that(length(n) == 1, n > 0L)
    if (n == Inf) {
        n <- -1
    }
    sql <- sql_render(x)
    res <- dbSendQuery(x$src$con, sql)
    on.exit(dbClearResult(res))
    out <- dbFetch(res, n)
    if (warn_incomplete) {
        res_warn_incomplete(res, "n = Inf")
    }
    grouped_df(out, groups(x))
}
```

Thus, we can conclude that the behaviour of `collect` has indeed changed in the manner originally described in my question.