# What do compute, collect, and collapse do in dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm now learning `dplyr` package in R, but hit the wall in understanding what the three functions - `compute`, `collect`, and `collapse` - do.

I understand that the `dplyr` doesn't use the type `data.frame` internally; it instead stores its data into its own type `tbl` or `tbl_df`.

Then, in order to convert the custom type back to R's default `data.frame` to utilize a set of default functions on `data.frame`, you must use `collect`, such as:

```
batting <- tbl(lahman_sqlite(), "Batting")
dim(collect(batting))
```

This returns `[1] 99846 22` as of 2016, while `dim(batting)` returns `[1] NA 22`.

However, I'm not sure what the other two functions - `compute` and `collapse` - do. If you check it out by `?collect`, the docs said the following:

> Description:
>
> ‘compute’ forces computation of lazy tbls, leaving data in the
>        remote source. ‘collect’ also forces computation, but will bring
>        data back into an R data.frame (stored in a ‘tbl_df’). ‘collapse’
>        doesn't force computation, but collapses a complex tbl into a form
>        that additional restrictions can be placed on.

What does this mean, specifically *forces computation of lazy tlbs*?

---

#### UPDATE

I would like to know what these functions do, and would like to get a clarification of what one does and the others don't.

Comment: To a person who voted to close this question, can you explain why you think this is too board and how can I improve it? My point is what the three functions do respectively.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I can see that the two votes-to-close have been cast under the category "too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: @Ben Yeah I checked it but I'm not even sure why it is too broad.

Comment: I think that most people cruising the new [tag:R] questions are generally looking for code they can copy-paste, run on their computer, and trouble-shoot to get a certain outcome specified by the poster. Questions that don't fit into this pattern tend to get punished with down/close votes, I guess that's what's happening here.

Comment: I'm not going to post as an answer because I'm not sure of myself, but: a *lazy tbl* means that tbl on which an operation has been specified, but not necessarily performed (because it isn't needed yet): see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazy-evaluation%20dplyr?sort=votes&mode=all

Answer (score 5):

From one of the [dplyr vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html):

> There are three ways to force the computation of a query:
>
> - `collect()` executes the query and returns the results to R.
> - `compute()` executes the query and stores the results in a temporary
>     table in the database.
> - `collapse()` turns the query into a table expression.
>
> `collect()` is the function you’ll use most. Once you reach the set of
>   operations you want, you use `collect()` to pull the data into a local
>   tbl_df(). If you know SQL, you can use `compute()` and `collapse()` to
>   optimise performance.

If that's not helpful, your best bet is probably studying the source code of each function. You can see instructions on how to do that here: [How do I see the help for the `dplyr::collect` method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714170/how-do-i-see-the-help-for-the-dplyrcollect-method)

Comment: Presumably, someone who's read the documentation (as indicated by OP) and asks here would find the source code less intelligible, no?

Answer (score 2):

`collect()` sends a query to the remote database and returns the result to R. Similar to `DBI::dbGetQuery()`.

`compute()` sends a query to the remote database, and creates a temporary table based on the result.

`collapse()` is more difficult to understand. I believe it forces intermediate SQL generation which is then used as a subquery.

Here is an example using `collapse()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)

db <- memdb_frame(a = c(3, 4, 1, 2), b = c(5, 1, 2, NA))


# No subquery
db %>% 
  mutate(a = 2 * b) %>% 
  # collapse() %>%
  arrange(a) %>%
  show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT 2.0 * `b` AS `a`, `b`
#> FROM `dbplyr_001`
#> ORDER BY `a`

# Intermediate sql used as subquery
db %>% 
  mutate(a = 2 * b) %>% 
  collapse() %>%
  arrange(a) %>%
  show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT *
#> FROM (
#> SELECT 2.0 * `b` AS `a`, `b`
#> FROM `dbplyr_001`
#> )
#> ORDER BY `a`
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>