# Seeking assistance to install several old R packages on PC running 64-bit, Windows 10

Tags: r

I am reaching out for help, I have a project that needs old versions (plural) of R.

Can anyone assist me to install several versions of R to run on R Studio?  An example of the old version of R is at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/

A nifty R script would be very handy.

MANY THANKS in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: How does one install an old version of R in Studio? Thank you

Comment: You install whatever version of R you want outside of RStudio, then point RStudio to the version of R you want to run: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop

Comment: Could you please provide more assistance... even installing out of R Studio. How would one install R from the link I gave above. Thank you

Comment: Well, that link is for R packages, If you want to install previous versions of R, you can get the installers from: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/

Comment: Then see this question for installing older versions of packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package

Comment: Sorry, MrFlick - I also have access to that repository. Could you walk me through the how to install any one of these versions of R?

Comment: Step 1) Download the installer for the version you want 2) Run the installer you downloaded.

Comment: MANY THANKS... was oblivious to the fact that these are*.exe files.