# Error in group_rows("SUCK", 2, 3) : unused arguments ("SUCK", 2, 3) in Kable

Tags: r

I have a problem with $\texttt{group_rows}$ when using $\texttt{kable()}$.

I did not have this problem before. I closed my .rmd file for one day and opened it this morning. Now, it cannot be knitted. I do not know what is going on. Everything works perfectly before I updated my packages in R.

```
data<- read.table("http://www.stat.umn.edu/~gary/book/fcdae.data/pr12.6",header=TRUE)
attach(data)

Lab.1 <- data[data$lab == 1, ]
Lab.2 <- data[data$lab == 2, ]
Lab.3 <- data[data$lab == 3, ]
Lab.4 <- data[data$lab == 4, ]
Lab.5 <- data[data$lab == 5, ]


Lab1.mat <- matrix(Lab.1$count, ncol = 8, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
Lab2.mat <- matrix(Lab.2$count, ncol = 8, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
Lab3.mat <- matrix(Lab.3$count, ncol = 8, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
Lab4.mat <- matrix(Lab.4$count, ncol = 8, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
Lab5.mat <- matrix(Lab.5$count, ncol = 8, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

m1 <- merge(Lab1.mat,Lab2.mat, all=T,sort = FALSE)
m2 <- merge(Lab3.mat,Lab4.mat, all=T,sort = FALSE)
m3 <- merge(m1,m2,all=T,sort = FALSE)
m <- merge(m3,Lab5.mat,all=T,sort = FALSE)
colnames(m)<- NULL

kable(m,"latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  group_rows("SUCK",1,2)
```

Any tip would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One option is to downgrade the package which caused the problem back to it's earlier version: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17082341/8366499

Comment: It works for me `kableExtra_0.9.0` `knitr_1.20`

Comment: OMG I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to add `kableExtra::` before `group_rows`? I met the same problem and this seems to work for me

```
kable(m,"latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  kableExtra::group_rows("SUCK",1,2) # add kableExtra:: here
```

I think the reason is that there is another `group_rows` function in `dplyr`. When you load `kableExtra`, it will automatically load `dplyr` for you so you need to specify the package you are using for this function.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Adam Ralphus No problem!