# Why I cannot download some packages in R 3.3.2 anymore?

Tags: r, dependencies, package, version

I am facing a weird problem with R. I used to load several packages with the function p_load (package pacman) in R 3.3.2. Yet I have not been able to load them since November the 1st this year, the following message appears when I try to load the packages:
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : there is no package called ...
Apparently R can not load some packages' dependencies.

I then downloaded R3.4.4 and am now able to load the packages.
(Computer 64 bits).

What is happening?

In addition, I tried to load the packages on R 3.4.4 on another computer (32 bits) and I got the same error as the one I got on my 64bits computer with R 3.3.2... whereas on R 3.3.2, I manage to load the packages on this 32 bits computer...

If someone could explain to me what is happening, it would be really helpful!

Thank you,

I.

Comment: Old R version. you are running into package dependencies. e.g. current version of pacman depends on R (≥ 3.5.0). The test suite being used depends on testthat (≥ 0.9.0). If the packages on the old computer have not been updated they will work on that machine. But 1 package update might break everything. You could look into the cran archives to find the packages that will work under R 3.3.2.  Seet [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package) on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I think it is clear for me now.