# Unable to install glmnet package on mac

Tags: r, package, glmnet

I tried to install package glmnet and set the dependencies=TRUE, it cannot install the package. And when I tried

```
setRepositories()
```

and chose CRAN (extras), it shows this error for installing "glmnet":

```
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2:
Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
```

My R version is 3.2.4.

I can't really find a similar situation online, I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me fix this! Thanks!

Comment: That's a fairly old version of R (released in March 2016). The current version of [`glmnet` requires R ≥ 3.6.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html). I think you need to update R. Then try re-installing `glmnet`.

Comment: PS. There are ways to [install older versions of R packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package); in my own personal opinion I'd advise against that. The R ecosystem benefits from the "release-early-release-often" principle, which requires you (or your sys admin) to maintain an up-to-date R environment including up-to-date external packages.

Comment: I fixed it by updating a new version, thank you so much!!