# Error when grouping data with dplyr and survey

Tags: r, dplyr, survey

I use the R-packages survey and srvyr in combination with dplyr to analyse survey data. However, when I try to calculate confidence intervals for groups`(see code below), I get the error **'group_by_drop_default' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'**

Thanks for any help regarding this error or calculating confidence intervals of groups in the survey framework in general.

````
  as_survey_design(strata = strata, weight  = weight_pers, id= hh_id, nest=TRUE)

out <- strat_design %>%
  group_by(sex, year) %>%
  summarize( var_mean= survey_mean(var1, vartype = "ci"),
            n = unweighted(n()))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like there is an incompatibility between your version of dplyr and srvyr.

dplyr introduced that function in [0.8.1](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/releases/tag/v0.8.1), and srvyr started to depend on it in version 0.3.6.

The easiest solution is to update dplyr with `install.packages("dplyr")`, but if you can’t update it then you could try to install an older version of srvyr ([stackoverflow post on how that would work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package))

Comment: Thank you, that did it.

Answer (score 1):

Your commands have some errors. I don't have your data, so I'll use the apistrat dataset from the survey package as an example. You can use this to modify your own commands accordingly.

```
library(survey)
library(srvyr)

data(api)

out <- apistrat %>%
  as_survey_design(strata = stype, weights = pw) %>%
  group_by(awards) %>%
  summarize( var_mean = survey_mean(api00, vartype = "ci"),
             n = unweighted(n()) )

out
```

---

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  awards var_mean var_mean_low var_mean_upp     n
  <fct>     <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <int>
1 No         634.         603.         664.    87
2 Yes        678.         655.         702.   113
```