# dependency ‘caTools’ is not available for package ‘gplots’

Tags: r, gplots

I am trying to install the gplots package (Xubuntu 18.04.03, R 3.4.4). gplots need caTools. But "dependency ‘caTools’ is not available for package ‘gplots’". This is on a fresh R install. My question is, how do I need to proceed to get gplots installed?

https://gist.github.com/antonkratz/119f7d3e6d677c7d6c9885644c749752

Comment: According to CRAN the latest version of caTools requires 3.6.0 (you are a few versions behind). You can install [an older version of that package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package) (i think 1.17.1 will do), but you have to install those separately.

Comment: @MrFlick: More like Xubuntu is a few versions behind but thank you, this answers my question! I cannot accept it b/c it is a comment but that resolves it.