# Install R package gplots for R version 3.4.4?

Tags: r, gplots

I am trying to install 'gplots' in R 3.4.4, however I keep getting the following error:

```
install.packages("gplots")
Installing package into ‘/home/u1983390/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: dependency ‘caTools’ is not available
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/gplots_3.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 516153 bytes (504 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 504 KB

ERROR: dependency ‘caTools’ is not available for package ‘gplots’
* removing ‘/home/u1983390/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/gplots’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmplw9pSu/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("gplots") :
  installation of package ‘gplots’ had non-zero exit status
> install.packages('caTools')
Installing package into ‘/home/u1983390/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘caTools’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

I believe this can be solved by installing a version of caTools compatible with R 3.4.4 following [this method](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages). However, I cannot find where older versions of caTools are (I have looked in the [CRAN archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/)).

Would anybody be able to direct me to an earlier version, or does anyone know a different method for instaling gplots?

Cheers,
Jamie

Comment: Your R version is two years old by now, consider to [update R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/).

Comment: Here's an old answer to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60744750/dependency-catools-is-not-available-for-package-gplots