# How can I use TeachingSampling package in R version 3.4.4?

Tags: r

I tried to install "TeachingSampling" package, using RStudio:

```
install.packages("TeachingSampling")
```

but got this warning:

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘TeachingSampling’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have to use R version 3.4.4? Because if you have an option to upgrade that is probably the best (and easiest) thing to do. Otherwise there is a possibility of building the package yourself from the source code but no need to do this if you can just upgrade R.

Comment: [According to CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=TeachingSampling) the latest version of that package requires at least R version 3.5. You are using an old version. It would be better to update your R to a newer version. Otherwise you could [install an older version of the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package)

Comment: Hi LSSousa. Welcome to SO. Try updating your Version of R. Version 4.0.0. has been released and 3.6.3. is still available.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for sharing. I have already uninstalled the old R version and i'm trying to reinstall (My OS is Ubuntu 18.04). I am using these commands:

cd Downloads \
tar -zxvf R-3.6.3.tar.gz \
cd R-3.6.3 \
./configure --enable-R-shlib \

After that, I'm trying to use these ones:

make \
sudo make install

However, when I type make, I got the following message: make: *** No target indicated and no make file found. Stop.

How can I deal with that?