# Problems Installing choroplethrZip@v1.5.0 3.5 R

Tags: r, choroplethr

Using the below code I got

```
install.packages("devtools") 
library(devtools)
install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0')
```

I'm trying to load this package but keep getting this error

> Installing 32 packages: farver, gridExtra, checkmate, e1071, uuid, rgdal, cpp11, DBI, classInt, selectr, hms, units, readr, rappdirs, tidyr, rvest, tigris, sf, png, jpeg, rjson, RgoogleMaps, RJSONIO, viridis, htmlTable, data.table, tidycensus, ggmap, WDI, Hmisc, acs, choroplethr
> Error: Failed to install 'choroplethrZip' from GitHub:
> (converted from warning) dependencies ‘latticeExtra’, ‘XML’ are not available

It asks me what part I want to update but no matter if I select one, two, all, or none. It gives me the same error.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You are running an old version of R and the current versions of the `latticeExtra` and `XML` packages don't run on that older version. It would be better if you updated to the latest version of R or [install an older version of those packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package) that will work with R3.5

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
install.packages(c("latticeExtra", "XML"))
```

and then try installing choroplethrZip again.