# Switching to another PC how can I automatically install all r packages I currently have installed (in the version that is maybe already superseded)?

Tags: r

I will to clone my r repository into another pc, how I can ensure to install the same packages in the same version I currently have installed in the other pc where the same repository is also cloned?

Comment: You should look into the [renv package](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html)

Comment: Old pc: store the output from `installed.packages()[,"Version"]`, with the package name and its version. New pc: follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/29840882/3358272. Imperfect but it's a start.

Comment: The "time machine" mirror maintained by Microsoft (MRAN: `snapshot` package)