# Ex-gaussian packages in R?

Tags: r, install.packages

I am currently using version 1.4.1106 of R Studio and version 4.0.4 of R. I am trying to install ex-gaussian packages such as retimes or exGAUS but am receiving the following errors:

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘retimes’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Are there other packages/versions that I might be able to install?

Comment: retimes was removed : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/retimes/index.html. You can install older versions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package

Comment: I also couldn't find an `exGAUS package` -- do you have a ref for it? But the web did suggest https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamlss.dist/index.html has an `exGAUS` function

Comment: Did you manage to install an archived version of this? I have been having issues but I haven't found a good equivalent for the retimes package to replace it