# How to successfully install older version of mapview? (and the dependencies)

Tags: r, powerbi, r-package, mapview

My end goal is to be able to import mapping functions from the package mapview into PowerBI. Unfortunately, PowerBI is only compatible with on older version of R (version 3.4.4), which is not compatible with the latest version of mapview. I then downloaded version 2.3 of mapview from here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mapview/ using the code below.

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.rproject.org/src/contrib/Archive/mapview/mapview_2.3.0.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

At this point I then get the error that the dependencies are unavailable for mapview. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/17082341/5784831?

Comment: Sure - pretty similar. I used their method installing from command line and have determined that it cannot successfully install due to the dependencies. That thread does not trouble shoot the dependencies issue.

Comment: Perhaps you should make that clear in the title? Perhaps you should also add which commant you used...