# R round_date to nearest quarter in lubridate v1.8.0

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a tibble with dates in one column I would like to round to the nearest quarter. Using lubridate::round_date() each date seems to just round down to the nearest quarter. I am trying to solve so that some dates round down and some dates round up.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

my_tibble <- tibble(my_dates = seq(ymd('2022-01-01'), ymd('2022-03-31'), by = 'days'))

my_tibble <- 
  my_tibble %>%
  mutate(qtr_date = round_date(my_dates, unit = "quarter"))
```

The early dates should round down, which they do:

```
> head(my_tibble)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  my_dates   qtr_date           
  <date>     <dttm>             
1 2022-01-01 2022-01-01 00:00:00
2 2022-01-02 2022-01-01 00:00:00
3 2022-01-03 2022-01-01 00:00:00
4 2022-01-04 2022-01-01 00:00:00
5 2022-01-05 2022-01-01 00:00:00
6 2022-01-06 2022-01-01 00:00:00
```

But the later dates also round down:

```
> tail(my_tibble)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  my_dates   qtr_date           
  <date>     <dttm>             
1 2022-03-26 2022-01-01 00:00:00
2 2022-03-27 2022-01-01 00:00:00
3 2022-03-28 2022-01-01 00:00:00
4 2022-03-29 2022-01-01 00:00:00
5 2022-03-30 2022-01-01 00:00:00
6 2022-03-31 2022-01-01 00:00:00
```

I was expecting the dates after the midpoint (2022-02-15) to round up to second quarter date.

If I wanted the dates in the quarter to always round up or round down I would have used cieling_date() or floor_date().

Is there someway to modify round_date() so that it actually rounds up or down?

---

Here is my info from sessioninfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lubridate_1.8.0 forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.9     purrr_0.3.4    
 [6] readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.2.0     tibble_3.1.6    ggplot2_3.3.6   tidyverse_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.7.0     compiler_4.2.0   dbplyr_2.1.1     tools_4.2.0     
 [6] jsonlite_1.8.0   lifecycle_1.0.1  gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.0.3     
[11] reprex_2.0.1     DBI_1.1.2        cli_3.3.0        rstudioapi_0.13  haven_2.5.0     
[16] xml2_1.3.3       withr_2.5.0      httr_1.4.3       fs_1.5.2         generics_0.1.2  
[21] vctrs_0.4.1      hms_1.1.1        grid_4.2.0       tidyselect_1.1.2 glue_1.6.2      
[26] R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.3      readxl_1.4.0     tzdb_0.3.0       modelr_0.1.8    
[31] magrittr_2.0.3   backports_1.4.1  scales_1.2.0     ellipsis_0.3.2   rvest_1.0.2     
[36] assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_2.0-3 utf8_1.2.2       stringi_1.7.6    munsell_0.5.0   
[41] broom_0.8.0      crayon_1.5.1
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. On my system, everything from 2022-02-15 (and above) gets rounded up to 2022-04-01; using your sample data and code.

Comment: Dang, I hate when stuff like that happens. Weird.

Comment: try in a new R session, with only the packages needed loaded.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use a new name for the modified tibble, in case you accidentally run the code twice.  I don't see how that would be the issue here, but it can cause confusion in some cases.  BTW, I see the same results as @Wimpel.

Comment: I turned my computer back on, started a new session of R, only loaded tidyverse and lubridate. I am still getting all dates rounded down to '2022-01-01'.

Comment: Could you add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your post?

Comment: You are not using the latest version of either R and/or the tidyverse/lubridate packages.. But i faul to see how that could cause the problem here... weird.

Comment: there seems to be an issue in `round_)date()`  with older versions.. . try updating your lubridate package to latest version, see: https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/1073

Comment: Yes, I installed the newest lubridate version and this fixed my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could replicate this issue in `lubridate` `v1.8.0`. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/blob/main/R/round.r#L178) for `round_date()` you will see that this function has been completely refactored. The work is now done by the line:

```r
timechange::time_round(x, unit = unit, week_start = as_week_start(week_start))
```

`round_date()` was previously calling `floor_date()` and `ceiling_date()` and finding which was nearest. We can see that this change was made in the [commit](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/commit/c4cb90143c9f9d437ad493c93d38bd540be57ca2#diff-6530cdec4c90e2f31d664264eb6d626ea1f827711403431a33f4afe27c3d8165R174) on November 4th 2022 (line 174).

This does not entirely explain why your code did not work, but knowing `round_date()` is now calculated differently, I updated `lubridate` to the latest CRAN version (`1.9.0`) with:

```r
install.packages("lubridate")
```

It is also possible to install a specific version of a package as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29840882/12545041).

Updating to `1.9.0` also installed [`timechange`](https://github.com/vspinu/timechange) as a dependency (`v.0.1.1`), which fixed the problem.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you! Once I moved to lubridate_1.9.0 it works as I intended.