# Debugging an environment issue for large package with tidyverse and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, environment

I'm trying to run a complex (and confidential) package that I use for work. I've run the package many times in the past, but am not able to run it now (in the interim, I likely updated R Studio and/or my installed packages). My coworkers are able run the package on their machines while using previous versions of the packages.

Tidyverse is a required package for the package that I am trying to use and is attached when I run the custom package (that was developed by a contractor for my company long before I joined who has since left). I'm able to match/load previous versions of the all tidyverse packages except for dplyr. I'm using 1.0.10 and my coworkers are using 1.0.8, but I get a tidyverse error message that it is no longer supporting versions of dplyr before 1.0.10.

Any thoughts on how I might go about debugging? I know that it's difficult without example code, but unfortunately I am not able to create a synthetic version and share.

I've tried debugging if it's a masking issue by using the conflicted package (i.e. conflict_prefer("mutate", "dplyr") and incorporating syntax (i.e. dplyr::mutate) throughout the function/script that is getting the error.

The error that I'm getting is:

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `*calculatedfield*= pmap(...)`. Caused by
> error in `gather()`: ! Can't subset columns that don't exist. x
> Columns `2020`, `2021`, `2022`, `2023`, `2024`, etc. don't exist.
> (These columns are present when running the script line by line and
> unnesting the tibble)

Comment: If it works on your coworkers machine, then try to install the older versions of packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package. The `tidyverse` package itself should have an older version as well. Since the `tidyverse` package it really just a collection of other packages, it shouldn't be a requirement to load it before loading a different package. The specific error could be caused by updates to functions. It looks like it's trying to use invalid/non-standard column names. Without knowing what the code is doing it's nearly impossible to help.

Comment: You can use the *archive* link on CRAN to access [an old version of `dplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/) and install it. You can also use the [checkpoint package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkpoint/index.html) for this. For future-proofing, you may want to look at solutions like [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html).

Comment: @GregorThomas  This is the message I get when trying to load the older dplyr version/package:Loading required package: tidyverse
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘dplyr’ 1.0.8 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.9 is required
Error: package ‘tidyverse’ could not be loaded

Comment: @MrFlick please see error message above

Comment: What version of `tidyverse` is installed on your coworkers computer? Are you sure it is the same as what you are using?

Comment: As Mr Flick said, sounds like you need to install an older version of `tidyverse` too. You can [go to the CRAN page for `tidyverse`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tidyverse), click the link where it say "old sources: tidyverse archive", and download and install an older version of `tidyverse`, perhaps one with a release date just a little bit after the `dplyr 1.0.9` release. Or ask your coworkers what `tidyverse` version they are using.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick Unfortunately, I've tried with previous Tidyverse packages. My coworkers are using tidyverse 1.3.0, and also dplyr 1.0.8, but I get the above message when I try to install tidyverse 1.3.0 and the install fails. The package/model that I am trying to run requires >=1.3.0 tidyverse. Any ideas why my coworkers are able to use this combo of tidyverse and dplyr versions but I am not able to load them?

Comment: also question for you @GregorThomas - thank you both for help trouble shooting!

Comment: It's not clear to me which error message you are getting when installing tidyverse. The messages you've shown seem specific to loading, not installing the package. Are you using the same R version? If you have the same R version you should be able to install the exact same versions of all the packages on your co-workers machine and get the same result. Perhaps you have a different version for a dependency or something. Look at `installed.packages()` on a working machine and install exactly those same package versions.