# I can't install the chain ladder package, it doesn't recognize my library. probably because of the program version

Tags: r

Error in package chain ladder
[image]

I tried to change in to previous versions, but it does not work

Comment: My version is 3.5.2

Comment: I think you're right.  The warning says the `actuar` package (for example) is unavailable.  Looking at the CRAN page (https://cran.r-project.org/package=actuar), it needs R 4.1.0 or newer.  Not sure if ChainLadder will work with an older version - you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package to install the packages mentioned in the warning (actuar, pbkrtest and RcppEigen), then retry your install

Comment: Or, you could just update R.

Comment: Look up date of your R version and then use that to pick contemporaneous package versions from the archive. (Or update R, since yours is a couple of years out of date.)