# How to install anomalize package in R version 4.2.2

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse

I'm trying to install the `"anomalize" package` in `R version 4.2.2`. I'm using a university device, and it takes a while for IT to respond, so I can't update my RStudio. I need to run some time series anomaly analysis.

I have tried installing with the `"groundhog package"`, which worked for `"timetk package"` but has failed to run for `"anomalize"`.

```
install.packages("groundhog")
library("groundhog")
groundhog.library("anomalize", "2023-02-20", tolerate.R.version='4.2.2') # version: 0.2.3
# also tried version 0.2.2 released "2020-10-09"
```

I got the error below:

```
    > groundhog.library("anomalize", "2023-02-09", tolerate.R.version='4.2.2')

groundhog says: will now look for 1 binary packages in MRAN (a Microsoft archive of CRAN).
MRAN is slower than CRAN, but faster than installing from source.
groundhog says: did not find any packages in MRAN

Will now attempt installing 2 packages from source.


groundhog says: Installing 'future_1.31.0', package #1 (from source) out of 2 needed
> As of 09:05, the best guess is that all 2 packages will install around 09:07, most likely before 09:10.

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com//src/contrib/Archive/future/future_1.31.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 335575 bytes (327 KB)
downloaded 327 KB

Will try again, now showing all installation output.
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com//src/contrib/Archive/future/future_1.31.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 335575 bytes (327 KB)
downloaded 327 KB

* installing *source* package 'future' ...
** package 'future' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
staged installation is only possible with locking
** using non-staged installation
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'globals' 0.14.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.16.1 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'future'
* removing 'C:/Users/saa815/Documents/R_groundhog/groundhog_library/R-4.2/future_1.31.0/future'
The package 'future_1.31.0' failed to install!



----------------   The package anomalize_0.2.2 did NOT install.  Read above for details  -----------------

Warning message:
In utils::install.packages(url, repos = NULL, lib = snowball$installation.path[k],  :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/saa815/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcV6w0o/downloaded_packages/future_1.31.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Then I decided to try this:

```
devtools::install_github("business-science/anomalize")
```

And got another error:

```
> devtools::install_github("business-science/anomalize")
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘htmlwidgets’
```

Because it specifies the required packages in the error message, I've tried to install them one after the other but that is taking very long.

Comment: may you can make conda environment and do the installation but there you won't have R studio you will have to work with jupyter notebook

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package

Comment: And this is the last version of the package: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/anomalize/anomalize_0.2.3.tar.gz

Comment: Hi Geo_CJ, did you manage to install the package? I have the same problem ... any hekp would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TiF, apologies for the late reply. I just used another computer and updated to the latest R.