# not able to install package httr in R

Tags: r, httr

Using R version **3.4.1**. Tryingg to install `httr` package like below

```r
install.packages('httr', keep_outputs = TRUE, repos='https://ftp.fau.de/cran/')
```

But there is no output, only one warning

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib/spark/R/lib’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

### Manually

Downloaded version to local and tried installing manually like below

```r
install.packages(pkgs = "/tmp/httr_1.4.6.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Getting error

```
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: this R is version 3.4.1, package 'httr' requires R >= 3.5
* removing ‘/usr/lib/spark/R/lib/httr’
```

### Questions

- Why R is not installing older version of `httr` package which is supported?
- Why R is not giving any error while installing `httr` in first way?
- I saw there is archive folder https://ftp.fau.de/cran/src/contrib/00Archive/. but why R is not installing from there?

Comment: [httr v 1.4.6](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html) requires R version >= 3.5 . You coud try an install an old version. Better is to upgrade R ( as 3.4.1 is almost 6 years old)

Comment: This may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package

Comment: R will always try to install the current version. If you want to install an older version, you must specify it. Looks like your version of R, 3.4.1, was released in [June 2017](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/), so I would recommend clicking the "old sources" link on the `httr` CRAN page and finding a version around that time, [httr version 1.3.1 looks promising](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/httr/).