# update packages installed from github

Tags: r, github, devtools

I'm using more and more dev packages installed from github.

I find myself wondering if there is an easy way to update these packages? 
Essentially looking for something like `update.packages()` equivalent for `install_github()` (or indeed any other repo than CRAN).

Similar question for R-forge has some ideas:

[Automatically update packages installed from R-forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971815/automatically-update-packages-installed-from-r-forge)

Maybe the best way to do this would be to install dev packages in their own separate directory:

[How to specify lib directory when installing development version R Packages from github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646065/how-to-specify-lib-directory-when-installing-development-version-r-packages-from)

keep a tab on packages as they are installed, and try re-installing list regularly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My [dtupdate](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/dtupdate) package helps with that.

Comment: In general, this is difficult because `CRAN` is a single repository, while `github` is a trillion separate repositories. That's why you need stuff like what @hrbrmstr refers to.  As to what happens if a `github` package has `CRAN` dependencies, I dunno :-)

Comment: Ok, that package does the trick nicely! I particularly like the ```whats_new()``` functionality to look over whether updating is a worthwhile risk? I presume that because packages are simply re-installed via ```github_install()```, ```CRAN``` and indeed other dependencies are taken care of?

Comment: @hrbrmstr Can you make that an answer?

Comment: you can also add a github repository as drat-repository via the [drat package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) from Dirk Eddelbuettel. After that you can use update.packages() on it

Comment: I usually use git bash to update the package with all the latest commits. You can find a list of useful git bash commands at https://services.github.com/on-demand/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of packages that will do this:

@hrbrmstr recommends the [dtupdate](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/dtupdate) package

@jeborsel suggests adding a github repository as drat-repository via the [drat package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) from Dirk Eddelbuettel. This will let you use update.packages() on it

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [pacman](https://github.com/trinker/pacman) package to install and load the current version of a package hosted on GitHub:

```
pkg = c('andschar/dbreport', 'Rdatatable/data.table')
pacman::p_load_current_gh(char = pkg)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call *install_github* again to get the most recent version of the package.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question as well as several of the comments do.